# Tikz-timing measuring the width of a signal

Tags: tikz-timing

I'm new to LaTeX and especially Tikz package. I would like to draw a timing diagram and measure the width of some signal with a double arrow and write on top the value. I have created this table:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/.style={x=1.75ex,y=2ex}]
AN0         & H5L35HL  \\
AN1         & H5H5L30HH \\
AN2         & H10H5L25HH \\
AN3         & H15H5L20HH \\
AN4         & H20H5L15HH \\
AN5         & H25H5L10HH \\
AN6         & H30H5L5HH \\
AN6         & H35H5LH \\
Cathodes    & D{}N(A1)N(A2)5D{Digit 0}N(B1)5D{Digit 1}5D{Digit 2}5D{Digit 3}5D{Digit 4}5D{Digit 5}5D{Digit 6}5D{Digit 7}N(B2)D{}\\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

I would like to show in the diagram the width of the signal called "Cathodes" from the beginning of "Digit 0" to the end of "Digit 0" and also from the beginning of "Digit 0" to the end of "Digit 7". Also I would like to write  a value on top of the arrow. Something like this:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!!